# OpenTelemetry Java Agent Not Receiving Arguments from SBT Build

Tags: java, scala, sbt, open-telemetry, javaagents

I'm currently facing an issue with the OpenTelemetry Java Agent not receiving the arguments I pass to it in my SBT build file. Here's a snippet from my build file:

```scala
val buildOpenTelemtryJavaAgent: JavaAgent.AgentModule = {
  val attributes = "service.name=MY_SERVICE,environment=development"
  val argsStr = s"""otel.exporter=otlp otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://198.51.100.1:4317 otel.resource.attributes="$attributes""""

  print(argsStr)
  JavaAgent(
    module = openTelemetryAgentPrefix % openTelemetryAgentModuleName % openTelemetryAgentVersion % "runtime",
    name = openTelemetryAgentName,
    scope = JavaAgent.AgentScope(true, true, true, true),
    arguments = argsStr
  )
}
```

I'm using the JavaAgent case class from the com.lightbend.sbt.javaagent (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-javaagent) package to attach the OpenTelemetry Java Agent to my application. I pass a string of arguments to the agent, but when I run my application, I get the following error:

```
[otel.javaagent 2023-05-16 06:45:58:127 +0000] [OkHttp http://localhost:4317/...] ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter - Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4317
```

This error message suggests that the agent isn't receiving the correct endpoint from my arguments and is instead trying to connect to localhost:4317. This occurs regardless of what IP address I set in my SBT build file.

However, when I manually run the agent using the following command, it works correctly:

```
-javaagent:/Users/[MY_USER]/dev/git/[MY_PROJECT]/target/scala-2.12/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.exporter=otlp -Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://198.51.100.1:4317 -Dotel.resource.attributes="service.name=MY_SERVICE,environment=development"
```

I would appreciate any insights into what might be going wrong here. Is it a problem with how I'm passing the arguments in my SBT build file, or is it an issue with how the agent is interpreting them?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the relation between the arguments passed at build time vs what's available to the Java agent at runtime? I'm no SBT expert, but usually, stuff in the build file is only relevant if you use the task to start the application. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: In my case, I am starting the application using the SBT build script. The javaAgents setting in the SBT build script is expected to apply the Java agent to the JVM at runtime, along with its arguments.

However, I am seeing a discrepancy. Despite specifying a non-local IP in the agent's arguments, it's trying to connect to localhost when started via SBT. Conversely, when I manually start the Java agent from the command line, it correctly connects to the provided IP. This inconsistency is the crux of my question. @AbhijitSarkar

Comment: Are you seeing the correct attributes being passed? If not, you may want to try by inlining the values instead of defining outside the `JavaAgent` block.

Comment: I see the right string is generated but I can't see these values from within the agent. I tried also to inline the values, passing just one value, without any help. @AbhijitSarkar

Comment: I’m gonna guess that your problem is caused by eager evaluation of the JavaAgent block. If you looked into their source code, you’d most likely see that the values being passed are the default ones. If they have a GitHub repo, you may have better luck opening a ticket there.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Thanks for your input. I understand your point about eager evaluation of the JavaAgent block, but I'm expecting the javaAgents setting to be evaluated at run time. That's why I'm puzzled as the arguments work when starting the agent from the command line.

Your suggestion to open an issue on their GitHub repo is noted. Meanwhile, if there's something I could be missing in the SBT configuration or application startup process, I'd appreciate any further insights.

Comment: There's an excellent blog post on this topic (not by me): https://ivan-kurchenko.medium.com/telemetry-with-scala-part-1-opentelemetry-758c72a136e7

It seems you should add the JVM args like this: `javaOptions += "-Dotel.javaagent.debug=true"`

Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/IvannKurchenko/536f326913e3ef821e7d19bee14645dd#file-blog-telemetry-code-4-scala)

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-javaagent `arguments` are "Java agent arguments", which get appended to the java agent like this: `-javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent.jar=arguments`